# Getting the color matrix and white balance info from Camera2 API (for custom raw processing)

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am working at an app where I need to take many pictures (possibly tens of thousands) and they have to be RAW, which I process in native code.
Right now I am converting the RAWs to DNGs, and in the native code I unpack them using libraw. I get the white balance color multipliers, and the color matrix from the dng.

However, converting the raw to dng and then processing the dng takes quite a bit of time, and I would like to skip this step, and process the raw info directly, without the DNG intermediary. But for that I need to get the color matrix and WB values. I did look at the docs, but I didn't find any way on how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is available in the CameraCharacteristics and [CaptureResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult) objects that you pass to [DngCreator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/DngCreator?hl=en), specifically fields like:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#sensor_calibration_transform1
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#sensor_color_transform1
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#sensor_forward_matrix1
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#sensor_reference_illuminant1
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult#SENSOR_NEUTRAL_COLOR_POINT

Most of those fields map basically directly to the DNG spec, but you can try to look at the DngCreator implementation to see how to go from the camera2 API to the DNG fields:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/jni/android_hardware_camera2_DngCreator.cpp;l=1217

While there's no official sample for using this information to process a raw buffer, the Android compliance tests include a simple RAW converter in Java, used to confirm that the resulting image reasonably matches the JPEG image provided by the device (to double-check that the various metadata fields are reasonably correct): https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:cts/tests/camera/src/android/hardware/camera2/cts/rs/RawConverter.java;l=279

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was going to do eventually, although this means I have to also look at libraw's source code to see where it gets some of the things from the dng file.

Comment: Well, after looking at the DNG specs more closely, I've noticed that libraw does a few other things such as creating a srgb matrix that can be directly applied to the raw data (after debayering), and there is no such matrix in Android. I guess there is more work involved than I originally anticipated :)

Comment: Creating that matrix requires making decisions about the desired white balance of the output image. Maybe libraw uses the DNG's recommended white point to create the matrix, but certainly most raw processors want to have opinions about white balance settings.  You may find this code useful: It's part of Android's compliance tests, implementing a simple raw to rgb converter using just the camera2 API: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:cts/tests/camera/src/android/hardware/camera2/cts/rs/RawConverter.java;l=279

Comment: Actually, libraw gives you that matrix plus the r,g,b white balance multipliers for each channel. I tried to look at the dcraw source code to see how that matrix is obtained, but it wasn't very intuitive from the code. I will look at that code when I do this final optimization of bypassing the dng format. Until then, I have a much bigger problem that I am unable to solve, regarding executing native code from a broadcast receiver class :/ Anyway, thanks a lot for your input, it's been very helpful.